# Getting individual MousePoint related to cell of JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouse, cell

I have JTable and right now I get the Point of a clicked point in a cell like this:

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

    JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();                        
    Point pMouse = new Point();
    pMouse = target.getMousePosition();
 }
}
```

When I click in a specific place in cell 1 I get:

> java.awt.Point[x=527,y=32]

If I click on the same place in cell2 I get:

> java.awt.Point[x=527,y=96]

The Y is different and that is of course because it's different cells. But how do I get so that both X and Y is the same when I click in the same place in different cells?

I need to get MousePoint relative to cell only.

Answer (score 2):

- I think that you looking for [JTable.rowAtPoint(Point point)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#rowAtPoint%28java.awt.Point%29), the same for ColumnModel
- don't forget to [convertColumnIndexToModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel%28int%29), the same for RowIndex (JTables view can be sorted, filtered, ColumnModel can be reordered, column(s) can be removed from JTables view too)
- for more info please to read Oracles JTable tutorial, part [Specifying Tool Tips for Cells](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#celltooltip)